# How to know if a function is called from the javascript console?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, console, hide

I want to know how can we hide a function from the javascript console so that it can't be called from it.

To let you better understand the problem , suppose that I have a javascript function that adds some records on the database using Ajax, and anyone else can use this function from the console to add as many records as he wants on the database. I want the function to be called from the web application and not from the console... I tried to obfuscate the code to hide it but we can still find the function from Google Chrome javascript console.

Comment: You can obfuscate, as you have done, but no, you can't totally "hide" a client side function from the client side (you can make it secure, and idempotent and such, but that's in the implementation, unrelated).

Comment: No way, even if it would be possible, you can still simulate the request with a browser or specific tool.

Comment: There's no such thing as JavaScript security on the client. You need to implement any security measures on the server.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to run a function from the console if it's not accessible globally/publicly. Where's that function at? It could be as simple as just wrapping everything in an IIFE.

Comment: All anyone has to do is to look at what your AJAX call sends over the network and make their own javascript to send that ajax.  You can't prevent this with obscurity.

Comment: @elclanrs: That wouldn't keep someone from doing what OP wants to prevent.

Comment: @thesystem honestly i don't think the OP really understands the nature of their problem which is why to those *in the know*, the OP question seems irrelevant to the greater problem. However elclanrs is technically answering his question directly.

Comment: @mikeymeows: elclanrs comment is very misleading to someone who doesn't know. Given that OP described the ultimate concern, it's most certainly not just as simple as wrapping in an IIFE. Even then, there's nothing preventing someone from re-running the script without the IIFE, making the functions reachable in the console.

Comment: @thesystem I feel you but like, in the simplest form; the question is "How can I hide my function from being called in the console?" and elclanrs' comment was helpful regardless since it did not define a solution but simply gave food for thought about the chance of something simpler being a possible solution. Whilst I think it's important that the OP understands that this is not a viable solution if he/she is attempting to create a secure database interface from their web app- they may at least come away with a basic solution to their immediate question.

Comment: @Mikey: Yeah, I would agree if that was their immediate question. But that really only represents the first two-thirds of the first sentence, and ignores the end of that sentence, and the title, not to mention the bottom paragraph. But whatever.

Comment: @thesystem we should probably stop arguing semantics but I still feel like suggesting an IIFE is at the least constructive and most definitely not misleading. As for the title, it really has nothing to do with the body of the question so that's something for the OP to make up their mind on which more to the point suggests that the OP is rather clueless as to what they want to figure out. It's my opinion I guess that any constructive help is help regardless in this context.

Answer (score 5):

**No matter how much you obfuscate and hide your code, any javascript that can be executed on the client side can be executed in the console and you should always be running permissions/security checks on the server side if you wish to have any real control over the security of such functions.**

**That being said**, you can restructure your code inside an immediately invoked function expression which will not be callable as easily from the console as usual like so:

```
(function() {
    var myUncallableFunction = function() { alert('meow'); }
})();
```

the function `myUncallableFunction` will only be able to be called from within the parent function as it is a local variable to that parent function and is therefore inaccessible outside of it.

You will still be able to call this function inside of that parent however like so:

```
(function() {
    var myUncallableFunction = function() { alert('meow'); }
    myUncallableFunction();
})();
```